# Parsing a hexadecimal string representation as an integer

Tags: c, algorithm, parsing

How can I parse a string like `"0000000f"` as an `unsigned long long int`? And for larger values, how can I parse a string like `"0000000f,0000000f"` representing respectively the upper and lower 32 bits?

P.S. Can't use library functions in this issue.

Comment: What's wrong with parsing `0000000f,0000000f` as two different unsigned long longs and ORing them together after 32 left bitshifts to the first?

Comment: `unsigned long long x = strtoull("0000000f", NULL, 16);`

Comment: I can't really use stdlib functions in this issue

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strtoull()` from `<stdlib.h>` this way:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned long long parse_u64(const char *s) {
    unsigned long long v1;

    v1 = strtoull(s, (char **)&s, 16);
    if (*s == ',') {
        v1 = (v1 << 32) | strtoull(s + 1, NULL, 16);
    }
    return v1;
}
```

Note that formatting errors are not detected.

If you cannot rely on library functions, use this:

```
int getdigit(int c) {
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') return c - '0';
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') return c - 'a' + 10;
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') return c - 'A' + 10;
    return -1;
}

unsigned long long parse_u64(const char *s) {
    unsigned long long v1;
    int digit;
    for (v1 = 0; *s; s++) {
        if (*s == ',')
            continue;
        digit = getdigit(*s);
        if (digit < 0)
            break;
        v1 = (v1 << 4) | digit;
    }
    return v1;
}
```

You can choose to ignore spaces and other characters or to stop parsing as I did.

Comment: this line: 'unsigned long v1;' should be: 'unsigned long long v1;'

Answer (score 1):

Like @chqrlie, but with additional error checking,

Sounds like you want a string to integer conversion.  Simply enough:

```
unsigned chtohex(char ch) {
  if (ch >= '0' &&  ch <= '9') return ch - '0';
  if (ch >= 'A' &&  ch <= 'Z') return ch - 'A' + 10;
  if (ch >= 'a' &&  ch <= 'a') return ch - 'a' + 10;
  return (unsigned) -1;
}

// return 0 on success,1 on failure
int my_hexstrtoull(const char *s, unsigned long long *dest) {
  unsigned long long sum = 0;
  unsigned ch;
  while (*s) {
    if (*s == ',') continue;
    unsigned ch = chtohex(*s++);
    if (ch >= 16) {
      return 1; // Bad hex char
    }
    if (sum >= ULLONG_MAX/16) {
      return 1; // overflow
    }
    sum = sum * 16 + ch;
    s++;
  }
  *dest = sum;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution using `scanf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned long long int parse(char const * s)
{
    unsigned long int a, b;
    if (sscanf(s, "%8lx,%8lx", &a, &b) == 2)
        return ((unsigned long long int) a << 32) + b;
    if (sscanf(s, "%8lx", &a) == 1)
        return a;

    abort();
}
```

Comment: I appreciate this and I should've mentioned it in the original post: can't rely on library functions.

Comment: the second call to scanf will fail because the input stream pointer will already be past  the data.  suggest saving the returned value from the first scanf.  then if returned value is 1 then process single input value else if input value is 2 then process dual input value else process input failure

Comment: suggest not using a length modifier in the input/conversion specifiers as the scanf would then fail if the input was not exactly 8 bytes per number

Comment: @user3629249: while I agree that the maximum field width is probably not needed, it is different from a *length modifier* that is used to specify the size of the receiving variable, such as `l`, `h`, `ll`, `hh`, `L` etc.  A maximum field width of `8` does not cause input failure if there are fewer hex digits, it just leaves any extra hex digits unparsed in the input stream. Input failure occurs if there are no hex digits after an optional string of white space characters.